# Uniform converge of a functional sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

I am supposed to determine if the function sequence

$$f_n\left ( x \right )=\frac{\ln nx}{nx}$$ converges uniformly on the interval $\left ( 0,\propto  \right )$.

Am I supposed to use Weirestrass criterion, or how should I solve it?

Comment: I don't understand your notation, what do you mean with $lnnx$?

Comment: @DavideMaran I edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f_n(x)=\frac{\log(nx)}{nx}$.  For $x>0$, we see that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(x)=0$$

So, $f_n(x)$ converges pointwise to $0$ on $(0,\infty)$

---

Note that $\frac{df_n(x)}{dx}=\frac{1-\log(nx)}{nx^2}$, from which it is easy to see that $f_n(x)$ attains its maximum value of $\frac{1}{e}$ at $nx=e$.  Hence, the convergence fails to be uniform on $(0,\infty)$.

---

For any fixed $x\ge\delta>0$, $f_n(x)$ decreasing in $n$ whenever $n>\frac{1}{\delta}$.  Hence, for $n\ge 1/\delta$

$$\frac{\log(nx)}{nx}\le \frac{\log(n\delta)}{n\delta}$$

and the convergence is uniform on $[\delta,\infty)$ for any $\delta>0$.

Comment: Thanks, can you please tell me, how you determine the maximum value?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  Let $f_n(x)=\frac{\log(nx)}{nx}$.  The maximum of $f_n$ can easily be found by differentiating and setting the derivative to $0$.

Answer (score 2):

Nothe that $f_n$ converges pointwise to zero. Now consider $x_n=1/n^2$ and use that point to show that
$$\sup_n |f_n(x)|\to 0$$
is false, so there is no uniform convergence

Comment: Why was this downvoted??

Comment: (+1) to neutralize the down vote.